# Ternary Operator Assignment Precedence to Variable

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

```
var url = age > 18 ? (
    alert("OK, you can go."),
    // alert returns "undefined", but it will be ignored because
    // isn't the last comma-separated value of the parenthesis
    "continue.html" // the value to be assigned if age > 18
) : (
    alert("You are much too young!"),
    alert("Sorry :-("), // Q2) ***When does it evaluate this line?
    // etc. etc.
    "stop.html" // the value to be assigned if !(age > 18) Q1) this line is evaluated first right?
);
location.assign(url); // "stop.html"
```

Question: When using a `ternary` operator, does it evaluate the rightmost term of the right operand?  So if I put in commas, then it would take the expression of the right-most comma.

If I called on this process against somehow would it evaluate the second right-most term, (Q2).

Is all of the false clause assigned to the variable? If so how come the output is only `stop.html` and does not include `Sorry` or `You are much too young!`?

Comment: Q: Why are you wasting time on something so perverse?  For "real code", you want to try to *avoid* indeterminate behavior, don't you? SUGGESTION: 1) substitute "Console.log()" for "alert()", 2) step through the code under the debugger, 3) be sure to try several different browsers.  For example, does Chrome behave differently from FF/Firebug?  IE11 differently from IE8?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Make sure you have popups enabled.

Comment: It is simply because all of the statements get executed but only the last return gets assigned. If you would use the `||` operator instead of `,` then it would stop at the first value with a value. But yes, this seems the _wrong_ use case for a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this little block of code to demonstrate now ternary works.

Given the code below:

```
function isGreater(a, b) {
    console.log('in isGreater');
    return a > b;
}

function isLess(a, b) {
    console.log('in isLess');
    return a < b;
}

function times2(v) {
    console.log('in times2');
    return v * 2;
}

function times3(v) {
    console.log('in times3');
    return v * 3;
}
```

Or (||) Scenario 1

```
// 1. isGreater is called and return true (since true so isLess is never called)
// 2. since true, only times2 is called
var x1 = isGreater(1, 0) || isLess(1, 0) ? times2(5) : times3(5);
console.log('x1 is ' + x1);
```

Output:

```
in isGreater
in times2
x1 is 10
```

Or (||) Scenario 2

```
// 1. isGreater is called, but return false
// 2. so isLess is called and return true
// 3. since true, only times2 is called
var x2 = isGreater(0, 1) || isLess(0, 1) ? times2(10) : times3(10);
console.log('x2 is ' + x2);
```

Output:

```
in isGreater
in isLess
in times2
x2 is 20
```

And (&&) Scenario 1

```
// 1. isGreater is called and return true
// 2. because true, isLess is called and return true
// 3. since both are true, only times2 is called
var x3 = isGreater(1, 0) && isLess(0, 1) ? times2(20) : times3(20);
console.log('x3 is ' + x3);
```

Output:

```
in isGreater
in isLess
in times2
x3 is 40
```

And (&&) Scenario 2

```
// 1. isGreater is called, but return false (since false, isLess is never called)
// 2. since false, only times3 is called
var x4 = isGreater(0, 1) && isLess(0, 1) ? times2(30) : times3(30);
console.log('x4 is ' + x4);
```

Output:

```
in isGreater
in times3
x4 is 90
```